# React Js Group By ID and Month from json using reduce or map function

Tags: reactjs, next.js, reduce

I want convert my below existing json to new json so that I can dynamically populate dropdowns.

Here I am grouping by **CityId** and extracting **month** from **DeptDate**

However unable filter days based on CityId wise.

Existing JSON :

```
const [items] = useState([
{"Id":502,"CityId":2,"CityName":"Ex. Mumbai","DepartureId":3762,"DeptDate":"22 Jul 2022 "},
{"Id":502,"CityId":2,"CityName":"Ex. Mumbai","DepartureId":3763,"DeptDate":"05 Aug 2022 "},
{"Id":502,"CityId":2,"CityName":"Ex. Mumbai","DepartureId":3764,"DeptDate":"12 Aug 2022 "},
{"Id":502,"CityId":2,"CityName":"Ex. Mumbai","DepartureId":3765,"DeptDate":"19 Aug 2022 "},
{"Id":502,"CityId":2,"CityName":"Ex. Mumbai","DepartureId":3766,"DeptDate":"26 Aug 2022 "},
{"Id":502,"CityId":2,"CityName":"Ex. Mumbai","DepartureId":3767,"DeptDate":"09 Sep 2022 "},
{"Id":502,"CityId":2,"CityName":"Ex. Mumbai","DepartureId":3768,"DeptDate":"23 Sep 2022 "},
{"Id":502,"CityId":1,"CityName":"Ex. Ahmedabad","DepartureId":3762,"DeptDate":"22 Jul 2022 "},
{"Id":502,"CityId":7,"CityName":"Ex. Delhi","DepartureId":3762,"DeptDate":"22 Jul 2022 "},
]);
```

to New JSON :

```
[
  {
    "Id": 502,
    "CityId": 2,
    "CityName": "Ex. Mumbai",
    "TravelDates": [
        {
            "DeptMonth": "Jul",
            "Dept": [
                {
                    "Day": "22"
                    "DepartureId": 3762,
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "DeptMonth": "Aug",
            "Dept": [
                {
                    "Day": "05"
                    "DepartureId": 3763,
                },
                {
                    "Day": "12"
                    "DepartureId": 3764,
                },
                {
                    "Day": "19"
                    "DepartureId": 3765,
                },
                {
                    "Day": "26"
                    "DepartureId": 3766,
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "DeptMonth": "Sep",
            "Dept": [
                {
                    "Day": "09"
                    "DepartureId": 3767,
                },
                {
                    "Day": "23"
                    "DepartureId": 3768,
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 502,
    "CityId": 1,
    "CityName": "Ex. Ahmedabad",
    "TravelDates": [
        {
            "DeptMonth": "Jul",
            "Dept": [
                {
                    "Day": "22"
                    "DepartureId": 3762,
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
  },
]
```

Currently I am using below reduce function but unable to achieve expected result.

```
const newJson = items.reduce((cityGroup, { CityName, CityId, DeptDate, DepartureId }) => {
    var [d, m, y] = DeptDate.split(' ');
    
    const day = `${d}`;
    const month = `${m}`;
    
    if (!cityGroup[month]) {
        cityGroup[month] = [];
    }
    
    // unable to group dates by month
    cityGroup[month].push({
            DeptMonth: month,
            Dept: [{
                Day : day,
                DepartureId : DepartureId
            }]
    });
    
    
    if (!cityGroup[CityName]) cityGroup[CityName] = [];
    
    cityGroup[CityName].push({
        CityName,
        CityId,
        TravelDates : [
            {
                // to be placed here...
            }
        ]
    });
    
    return cityGroup;
}, {});

console.log(newJson);
```

Please guide and thank you in advance for all support !!

Comment: @iamhuynq can you please support as well !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always prefer immutable data structures. This is how you could achieve it. You should be able to fill in the blank for your solution as well from here.

```
const groupByCityAndTravelDates = (arr) => arr.reduce((acc , cur) => {
  const existing = acc[cur['CityId']];
  const [d , m , y] = cur['DeptDate'].split(' ');
  if (existing) {
    const existingTravelDate = acc[cur['CityId']]['TravelDates'][m];
    if (existingTravelDate) {
      return {
        ...acc ,
        [cur['CityId']]: {
          ...acc[cur['CityId']] ,
          'TravelDates': {
            ...acc[cur['CityId']]['TravelDates'] ,
            [m]: {
              'DeptMonth': m ,
              'Dept': [
                ...acc[cur['CityId']]['TravelDates'][m]['Dept'] ,
                {
                  'DeptDay': d ,
                  'DepartureId': cur['DepartureId'] ,
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      };
    }
    return {
      ...acc ,
      [cur['CityId']]: {
        ...acc[cur['CityId']] ,
        'TravelDates': {
          ...acc[cur['CityId']]['TravelDates'] ,
          [m]: {
            'DeptMonth': m ,
            'Dept': [
              {
                'DeptDay': d ,
                'DepartureId': cur['DepartureId'] ,
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    };
  }

  return {
    ...acc ,
    [cur['CityId']]: {
      'Id': cur['Id'] ,
      'CityId': cur['CityId'] ,
      'CityName': cur['CityName'] ,
      'TravelDates': {
        [m]: {
          'DeptMonth': m ,
          'Dept': [
            {
              'DeptDay': d ,
              'DepartureId': cur['DepartureId'] ,
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  };
} , {});

const toCityArray = (mappedData) => Object.keys(mappedData).map(key => {
  return {
    'CityId': key,
    'Id': mappedData[key]['Id'],
    'CityName': mappedData[key]['CityName'],
    'TravelDates': Object.keys(mappedData[key]['TravelDates']).map(travelKey => {
      return {
        'DeptMonth': travelKey,
        'Dept': mappedData[key]['TravelDates'][travelKey]['Dept']
      }
    })
  }
})

toCityArray(groupByCityAndTravelDates(arr))
```

I have some takeaways for you

- You will have to consider `year` for aggregation alongwith `month` at some point of time in the solution.
- In general, its recommmended to use `camelCase` for json attributes.
- I am sure you are pulling this data from an api. Its not recommended to do a lot of aggregation on the frontend, specially if the data grows. If possible transfer this aggregation to the api.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You @g.p for your support. I have note down your "takeaways" and surely consider this points specially point 1 & 3 .